# How can I completely uninstall DataStax Studio on Windows 10?

Tags: datastax, datastax-studio

How can I completely uninstall DataStax Studio on Windows 10?

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise version 1709.
I installed DataStax Studio 2.0.0 from the ZIP file (datastax-studio-2.0.0.zip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the extracted directory from disk?

Comment: Excellent. I also needed to delete my user data, which was being stored in **C:\Users\<username>\.datastax_studio\.**